# Upgrade Windows 7 to Windows 10 via MDT: The system registry cointains invalid file paths

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, windows-installation, mdt

I try to upgrade Windows 7 machines to Windows 10 with MDT Microsoft Deployment Tool. The installation is getting stuck at 30% after a reboot. I tried several solutions but none of them worked.

```
Delete entries in system variables.
Delete drive letter on system reserved partition (is not the case).
Repairing windows 10 system files

DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth
sfc /scannow
```

It is not an option to upgrade the machines with a Windows 10 ISO file, we have 130 stores all around the country. Do you guys have any idea?

I have different errors in de C:$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\Panther\setuperr.log file. But there are a lot of errors and I don't know which one is the correct one to start with. At the end of the line I have those two errors.

```
2021-11-09 15:18:34, Error      [0x0803eb] MIG    Error: 161 Message: Error opening the key HKLM\SOFTWARE\\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\TabletPC: The specified path is invalid. [0x000000A1][gle=0x00000002]



2021-11-09 15:18:44, Error      [0x0808fe] MIG    Plugin {0b23c863-4410-4153-8733-a60c9b1990fb}: TableTextServiceMig!RemoveObsoleteCHSHKLMRegkey - fail to open regkey (software\Microsoft\CTF\TIP\{E429B25A-E5D3-4D1F-9BE3-0C608477E3A1}\LanguageProfile\0x00000804) = 2
```

Comment: It the title you have mentioned an error message that is not mentioned in your question. Where does this error message come from?

Comment: @Robert i have updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

This exact problem is discussed in the post
[Issue when updateing from windows 7 pro to windows 10 pro](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/issue-when-updateing-from-windows-7-pro-to-windows/e897871d-19e6-45c9-a332-ac585be25aac?auth=1).

Three workarounds were mentioned which worked for some (but not for
everyone), as follows.

**1. Incorrect PATH**

One poster deleted everything in Path under System Variables except
the following:

`%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\`

Check if you have any unnecessary item in the PATH in addition to the
above entries.

**2. Assigning drive letter 'A' to the "System Reserved" partition**

This was done using Disk Management.
It seems like a weird solution, but it was reported as working by one guy.

**3. Tweaking.com windows repair**

The poster downloaded and ran
[Tweaking.com - Windows Repair Portable](https://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/tweaking_com_windows_repair_portable.html)
and reports:

> I can't remember which items exactly I ticked but pretty much resetting all the services, Windows update, firewall etc. Then rebooted and tried the Win10 1909 upgrade, and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Tried already the steps. But will not use tweaking software in a company.

Comment: Your options are then somewhat limited.